# HTML-<h1>, <p> wont display in my <div>

Tags: html, css

Firstly I attempted the only way I can think of to add 3 different
colours for the background, but now it won't allow me to display my
text.

I tried to use the position feature but it doesn't work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong or is there a better way to do the 3 colour background?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}

.a {
  background: black;
}

.b {
  background: #1e1d1d;
}

.a:after,
.c:before,
.c:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.a:after {
  background: black;
}

.c:before {
  background: #1e1d1d;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.c:after {
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <h1>DeadTreeStudios</h1>
</div>
<div class="b" style="position:absolute;">
  <h1>
    -I'm James, a freelance software developer & designer.
  </h1>

  <p>
    I've always had a keen interest in design and development. Allthough there is always alot to learn, my skills are broad: from front end to back end development to app development. I enjoy it all!
  </p>
  <p>
    I'm avaliable for remote work, or if you like to build somthing together, please get in touch.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
<article></article>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. Also this is not going to be hosted, this website is for my courses and ive only been studying for less than a week. but thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple things wrong with your css that broke it, check this out.

You don't need `position: absolute` to do stuff like this

with `height: 100vh;  width: 100%;` i make sure a section is filling the screen from top to bottom left to right
note that you could also use `width:100vw;` to fill it horizontally but in some cases it adds a horizontal scroll bar

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: arial;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#first {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 48vh;
}

#second {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

#first h1 {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="first">
  <h1>DeadTreeStudios</h1>
</section>

<section id="second">
  <h1>
    -I'm James, a freelance software developer &amp; designer.
  </h1>
  <p>
    I've always had a keen interest in design and development. Allthough there is always alot to learn, my skills are broad: from front end to back end development to app development. I enjoy it all!
    <br> I'm avaliable for remote work, or if you like to build somthing together, please get in touch.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="third">

</section>
```

Comment: i'd like to hear from you if there is something incompatable with what you are trying to acomplish, that way i can provide additional help

Comment: ah so you can do it in sections, makes sense. i'm new to this and didnt know about id. Thanks for the help. And thanks for the additional help offer, means a lot. will let you know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just fiddled your stuff.

I removed the

```
position:absolute;
```

inline style....
and gave .a and .b a color ofc you cant see black on black....

https://jsfiddle.net/nabrzovg/

Comment: Ah i understand, thanks for the help. I can now play around with it some more and figure out how to align it. thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what you are trying to do here. I removed all positions and changed colors to see whats happening.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    height: 1500px;
}

.a {
    background: red;
}

.b {
    background: yellow;
    z-index:22;
}

.a:after, .c:before, .c:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 200px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;

}

.a:after {
    background: black;
}

.c:before {
    background: purple;
}

.c:after {
    background: white;
}
p{ 
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
}
h1{
    color: white;
}
```